# How to distribute rectangles with minimum overlap

Tags: algorithm, overlap, rectangles, packing

Basically I need to distribute various rectangles in a bigger rectangle randomly. So:

1. While there is enough space, rectangles don't overlap or overlap just a bit.
2. When there is not enough space rectangles overlap but still trying to overlap as little as possible (so they all stack in one place).

I **don't need** classical ideal top-left to bottom-right packing. The point is that I need random spread.

At first I tried to brute-force it by randomly selecting position for a rectangle and then comparing collision with all rectangles that were already placed. Not ideal, obviously.

Then I tried to assign "points" to the space and place rectangles near these points. The closer rectangle was to a point the more "pressure" it applied to it. And that pressure stacked for each rectangle that was placed. Algorithm tried to place rectangles near points with minimal pressure. Unfortunately this resulted in rectangles stacking near top-left and bottom-right corners.

[image]

(If you'll close this one too I don't even know what more info do you need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want any overlap you can use method called sweeping to find all 
possible spots for middle of new rectangle. It can be divided into rectangles, then calculate area of each one and choose one randomly with respective ratios. If that is good solution ask for more details.

And if they can overlap, let's say 10% then just make rectangles smaller than 10%, distribute them and them inflate back.

Comment: Yeah this sounds like it could work. Are you talking about Sweep line algorithm? Please explain how this works because looking at Wiki page I have no idea what I should do.

Comment: Ok, so I think I figured this out. Iterate through X coordinate and project existing rectangles onto this vertical line. Record their beginning and ending points then sort them by Y from lower to bigger. Get "free space" sections from these points and then compare them with sections from a previous step to figure out which areas continue and which end. Construct "free space" rectangles, check which are big enough and place new rectangle in them.

Comment: @user64675 Yes, very nice. One more hint, when you wanna fit new rectangle (say 10 x 30) you can increase sizes of all others, then count free space and it is where the middle can be. But otherwise you said it really nice.

Comment: From what I can see it seems that it would be better to use vertical and horizontal sweeps together since they detect different rectangles. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't really understand, you can detect all in one sweep.

Comment: Then I have a problem with the algorithm, because I can only detect rectangles from left to right (green on the image). To detect red ones I would need to perform horizontal sweep. https://i.ibb.co/1ZZdKcd/problem.png

Comment: But green ones are enough. I mean you can just randomize middle of new rectangle somewhere inside the green rectangle.

Comment: At first I'm trying to randomize between rectangles that are big enough to actually contain new rectangle. And only if I can't find them I just select any other available. Green rectangles have smaller width, which means that there is a chance that a new rectangle won't fit, because it's width will be bigger than green rects width.

Comment: So if you wanna fit a rectangle with dimensions `n x m`. Increase all rectangles by `n/2` and `m/2`. Then find green rectangles. Then choose middle somewhere in green rectangle it WON'T have any overlap with original rectangles.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work because from what I can see it won't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208873/discussion-between-miszcz2137-and-user64675).

Comment: I want to achieve the exact same thing but I had trouble to understand this response. Would you mind explaining a bit more?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can divide the screen and randomly distribute the rectangles on the divided area. If they overlap, remove the last step, find another area randomly on screen and start to distribute.

Divide the screen n parts and randomly select a part from it and store it. If it recures again, neglect it and move on and continue to fill it with rectangles. You can shape this shapes similar to shapes of rectangles and write another algorithm for it. Like puzzle you will find the pieces from your collect of rectangles in try to fit every figure fit approximate figure to the puzzle. So, transforming problem to that way may help. You can turn the problem a random fitting to pieces to puzzle problem. Good luck.

- Step 1: randomly select and area,
- Step 2: distribute the rectangle,
- Step 3: If overlap ,remove the last step,
- Step 4: If overlap , select new area randomly,

You can loop this process.

Comment: This is what I initially tried. I'm trying to find a better aglorithm rather than just bruteforce it.